# Bash permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm a beginner with bash and I don't understand why

```
#! /bin/sh
if ! [ -d $1 ]; then echo This is not a directory && exit 1; fi

for file in `ls $1`; 
do 
    if [ -f `$1/$file` ]; then
        echo $file is a file
    elif [ -d $file ]; then
        echo $file is a directory
    fi
done
```

gives me permission denied on `[ -f`$1/$file`]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have surrounded the path with backticks (``) in the "if" line. That's telling the shell to execute the file (and no doubt many of the files in the folder aren't executable - hence the error). Switch to ordinary quotes.

As an aside, using backticks to capture the output of "ls" in the "for" loop is a bad idea - it will break on filenames that contain spaces (which are perfectly legal).

Comment: Thank you, that was stupid...I'm not familiar with backticks, I confuse them with quotes :/ What should I do instead of using 'ls'? Is a cd $1 and then for i in * the best solution?

Comment: Use `for file in "$1"/*; do ...; done`.  The shell preserves the proper handling of file names - preserving spaces and newlines etc inside individual names, which the back quotes mechanism can't do.  You just have to worry about an empty directory; that will return the name `*` by default (see `nullglob` option).  If the path is unacceptable, then for your code: `(cd "$1"; for file in *; do ...; done)`.